# Does HHVM Proxygen support the HTTP Patch method?

Tags: php, httprequest, lumen, hhvm, proxygen

Our application runs on a [*hhvm/proxygen* docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/hhvm/hhvm-proxygen/). When we try to use the http patch method we always get a "Bad Request 400" response. Do I need a special configuration to use **patch** on *hhvm/proxygen*?

The php application is based on Lumen (Laravel), but to me it seems not to be related to our sourcecode.

Comment: Bad request is not a 404 code. I'm confused

Comment: Was a typo on my side it's __400__, thank you.

Comment: Well it depends how you're using the patch method and if lumen is configured to listen and handle patch requests (e.g. via a restful controller)

Comment: The lumen side seems to be fine, I can replace __patch__ by __put__ and every thing works like a charm. So it seems to be an hhvm/proxygen issue.